# Update database with html Switch Checkbox php if statement

Tags: php, html, checkbox

Hope someone help sort this for me, even if its another solution, as I have hit the php brick wall

I have a form with a checkbox switch in it

```
                       <div class="col-md-3">
                        <input type="hidden" name="needclean" value="No" checked />
                        <div class="switch">
                        <label>NO<input type="checkbox" name="needclean" value="Yes"><span class="lever switch-col-green"></span>YES</label>
                        </div>
                        </div>
```

What I want to happen is when the user clicks "Yes" it populates the cell in the DB called "Status" to "Needs Cleaning" and if the user Clicks "No" it populates the "Status" cell in the DB to "Good to Go"

I have tried this

```
<?php
                    if(isset($_POST['needclean'])){
                    $clean = $_POST['needclean'];
                }
                if(isset($needclean) == "Yes"){ 
                    echo '<input type="hidden" name="status" value="Needs Cleaning" />';
                } else {
                     echo '<input type="hidden" name="status" value="Good to Go" />';
                }

                    ?>
```

But all it does is populate the "Status" cell with "Good to go" no matter if I select Yes or No

I hope I have explained this and if you need any more info please let me know

Thanks in advance for any help

Comment: `isset()` returns __true/false__.

Comment: to add the if statement is "needclean" now, just didnt update it sorry

Comment: Most likely `if(isset($needclean) == "Yes")` needs to be `if($clean == "Yes"){ `

Answer (score 0):

Remove the input type hidded, do this:

```
if(isset($_POST['needclean']) { echo  "is checked";} else { echo "Not checked";}
```

Comment: I cannot remove the hidden part as this also updates a different cell in DB, even if I do remove it still does not work

Comment: The echo outputs do not correspond to the checked state?

Comment: Sorry I do not understand what you mean